# Webform emails flagged as spam, emails sent from outside Drupal not flagged

Tags: webforms, advertising

Our Drupal installation uses Webform and Mime Mail. Emails sent from our webforms are getting flagged as spam by Gmail and other providers. We also have some email scripts running on our server outside Drupal whose emails are not getting flagged as spam, so I know our IP address has not been blacklisted. I've spent some time tinkering with the headers on the webform emails, to no avail. Here are the headers from one of our Webform emails:

```
Delivered-To: jesseloesberg@gmail.com
Received: by 10.114.109.35 with SMTP id hp3csp217457ldb;
    Fri, 5 Dec 2014 10:42:48 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.66.248.36 with SMTP id yj4mr30814419pac.51.1417804967335;
    Fri, 05 Dec 2014 10:42:47 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <mslavin@hnu.edu>
Received: from 69-64-86-100.phx.dedicated.codero.com ([69.64.86.100])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id da5si48803543pdb.204.2014.12.05.10.42.46
    for <jesseloesberg@gmail.com>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Fri, 05 Dec 2014 10:42:47 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of mslavin@hnu.edu designates 69.64.86.100 as permitted sender) client-ip=69.64.86.100;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of mslavin@hnu.edu designates 69.64.86.100 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=mslavin@hnu.edu
Received: from nobody by 69-64-86-100.phx.dedicated.codero.com with local (Exim 4.84)
(envelope-from <mslavin@hnu.edu>)
id 1Xwxq1-0002dQ-TD
for jesseloesberg@gmail.com; Fri, 05 Dec 2014 11:42:45 -0700
To: jesseloesberg@gmail.com
Subject: Your recent interest in HNU
X-PHP-Script: www.hnu.edu/index.php for 107.1.132.130
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;
boundary="2f4e6192994ec7ee1ec9251859f0041c248e044c1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8Bit
X-Mailer:Drupal Webform (PHP/5.4.30)
From:"Matt Slavin" <mslavin@hnu.edu>
Reply-To:mslavin@hnu.edu
Message-Id: <E1Xwxq1-0002dQ-TD@69-64-86-100.phx.dedicated.codero.com>
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 11:42:45 -0700
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - 69-64-86-100.phx.dedicated.codero.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [99 99] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - hnu.edu
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: 69-64-86-100.phx.dedicated.codero.com: uid via acl_c_vhost_owner from authenticated_id: nobody from /only user confirmed/virtual account not confirmed
```

Any thoughts about why these emails are getting flagged where our non-Webform emails are not are greatly appreciated.